# Prevent Chrome notification from displaying after certain amount of time?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have created a [`Chrome extension`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions) that creates a [`Chrome notification`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications) every time a specific game starts playing (on a server), so that the user can join in a reasonable amount of time.

However, I have an issue where if you have an application in fullscreen (on Windows), Chrome will wait to send those notifications until after you've left fullscreen mode. This means that it will stack up all notifications from the time that you entered fullscreen mode, to the time that you left it, and then proceeds to display all of them at once. This is an issue because the notifications I'm creating are only relevant for a short period of time, and quickly become useless to the user (and misleading), as when they see the notification, they assume that the game has just started, and isn't a notification that was saved from five minutes ago.

So with that being said, is there any sort of way to prevent a `Chrome notification` from being displayed after a certain amount of time (i.e. one minute)? If that's not possible, could you possibly prevent a notification from being sent at all if it isn't going to be displayed the second it was meant to be shown?

Comment: csn you detect fullscreen mode so you yourself queue them up for later?

Answer (score 0):

yes. when you .create a notification, you can pass it a unique notificationId or let chrome generate one.
then use setTimeout to call .clear after your expiration time.
 https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications#method-clear